# C# At opening large Excel file (150MB) by OledbConnection System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#

I have to open a large excel file 150MB with half millon of records (excel 2007 .xlsx file) , and i have to migrate it to sql server, I use oledbconnection , however when I try to open the connection it takes more than 5 minutes and after that a System.OutMemoryExcepion appears. I think this connection tries to open all file in memory , how can I read row by row.
I am working with Visual Net 2005 and C#

```
string archivoExcel="c:\largeExcel.xlsx"
string conneStringInraSIS = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                    "Data Source=" + archivoExcel + ";" +
                                    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'";


OleDbConnection connexcel = new OleDbConnection(conneStringInraSIS);
connexcel.Open();
```

Comment: You should build your connection string using `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` instead of manually concatenating the string, or you'll fail if the filename has a `'`.

Comment: What is in the file? Can it be saved in a CSV format instead? Also, 2007 Excel is just a bunch of zipped up XML files. You can manipulate those directly with a text reader, reading say 1,000 lines at a time.

Comment: Can you make this process simpler, by converting that excel file to CSV and, maybe, importing it directly to your SQL database?

Comment: Thanks for your help, My client wants to migrate from their excel files alot of information, I have to do some bussines logic too. Besides that My client wants to update some records of other excel files. so I have to work with large excel files. if there is no way to read row by row an excel file, i do not know what to do .

Answer (score 1):

Priority #1 should be getting the data out of the xlsx spreadsheet. Apply business logic once this has occurred. I'd export CSV from the sheets and deal with them.

Comment: This progrma is for a manager who has a lot of excel files, he gets these file from other people , he wants 2 things 1.- upload all files in a SQL server database and get reports. 2.- update these excel files (sheets and fields that he choose)with some database information

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue. The best thing I found in dealing with this problem is that go to codeplex.com and download Excel.dll. This dll will solve this issue very easily. Using this you can directly save your data to a dataset and do what ever you want to do with it then. You would find a sample code at site.

Answer (score 0):

New Answer (based on information in comments):

Look into VSTO.  I would create an addin that would allow the manager to click a ribbon button to upload the data into SQL Server, and then retrieve information from SQL Server (this will allow Excel to handle its own files, exactly how it does best).

Here is a link that should get you started:  [MSDN Code Sample](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f220681f-fbe5-4ad1-b517-229079a16cb4&displaylang=en)

and you can download VSTO [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5E86CAB3-6FD6-4955-B979-E1676DB6B3CB&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thanks but I have bussiness logic to do and I have to update the excel file i do not know what to do

Comment: What kind of business logic?  What do you mean you have to update the file?  - Depending on what you are attempting, you might be able to do that within SSIS

Comment: If you want, though, you can convert the xlsx file to a csv file.  Then use this link to load the csv file efficiently:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: This progrma is for a manager who has a lot of excel files, he gets these file from other people , he wants 2 things
1.- upload all files in a SQL server database and get reports.
2.- update these excel files (sheets and fields that he choose)with some database  information.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments suggested exporting the Excel files to CSV and parsing the CSV file line by line, but that seems to not be a solution to your problem.

What you can do however is use the Excel ActiveX objects to open the xlsx file and save it as a CSV from code.  The [Workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210376.aspx) object has a [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129.aspx) method that takes a file format.

So you can get the CSV data straight from the xlsx file and not have to have your clients worry about it.

This assumes that you have Excel installed on the system running this process.